# How to pass BotEngine attributes via BotEngine webhook back to my backend

Tags: webhooks, chatbot

I've been digging around on BotEngine's documentations and their backend for this but haven't found anything solid. Any hints or pointing for directions are very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it, basically as long as an attribute is defined in a interaction, the attribute's value will be passed to the corresponding webhook in the request body.